# How can I copy a file from a usb drive to a directory on the hard drive in windows 7 using command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, usb-storage

How can I copy a file from a pen drive to particular  directory on the hard drive  in windows 7 using command prompt in quickly compare to ordinary copy paste.

Scenario 1: need to copy the files from particular directory which is present in pen drive to particular directory which is present in system hard drive

```
source path: F:\aaa\bbb\  (F: is pendrive)
target path: D:\xxx\yyy\
```

Scenario 2: need to copy all files from  pen drive to particular directory which is present in system hard drive

```
source path: F: (F: is pendrive)
target path: D:\xxx\yyy\
```

Note:- the cmd need to do  copy/paste in faster compare to ordinary method

Comment: why do you think cmd should be faster? In the background the process of copy-paste are the same either with GUI or with cmd. With GUI, the user gets to know what is happening (progress, file being copied, estimated time of completion etc.,) whereas in cmd it does not shown. I'm not convinced that cmd copy-paste action is faster than the one with GUI

Comment: Command line is only useful if you do this a lot and want to automate it. Other than that i don't think you will notice the speed difference.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 1

```
copy F:\aaa\bbb\file.name D:\xxx\yyy\
```

Scenario 2

```
copy F:\aaa\bbb\*.* D:\xxx\yyy\
```

Type `copy /?` for more help.

SuperUser would probably be a better place to ask this question.